# Подскажите как получить html страницу в языке Rust, в синхронном коде без использования библиотек : future, reqwest::blocking

Tags: request, rust

Коллеги помогите пожалуйста, мне нужно сделать функцию которая по ссылке будет получать html страницу. Так как я использую библиотеку "yew" то WASM не позволяет мне использовать многие пользовательские библиотеки и функции. Например библиотеку "Tokio", "future" и функцию reqwest::blocking::get()

У меня был примерно такой код который работает в тестовом файле Rust:

```
pub fn get_response(){
    let link = "url";
    let response = reqwest::blocking::get(link).unwrap();
    let res = response.text().unwrap();
    
}
```

Но как я уже сказал библиотека "yew" не позволяет мне использовать "blocking::get()" как мне сделать такую же функцию но без использования blocking::get()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать крейт reqwasm для этой задачи.
Код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
use reqwasm::http::Request;

pub fn get_response() {
 let mut response = Request::get(url)
    .send()
    .await
    .unwrap();
// Далее можно манипулировать полученными данными
}
```